# The value of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cos^{2} nx dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Using the fact  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cos nx dx=0$ ,find the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cos^{2} nx dx.$$

I tried through integrating by parts , also through the $1^{st}$ Mean Value Theorem of integral calculus but I c

Comment: The problem can be genralized, and the result is $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x) \cos ^{2 n}(x) \, dx=\frac{\binom{2 n}{n} }{4^n} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x) \, dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cos^{2} nx \,dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{\cos 2nx + 1}{2} \,dx$$

Comment: If that is not enough of a hint, try to think whether you know another theorem almost like it...

Comment: @GEdgar are you suggesting me to put in Reimann-Lebesgue lemma as a hint too?

Comment: No, I was asking Panja to remember the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

$$\cos(2t) =2\cos^2 t - 1$$

Comment: What's the down vote for? If this answer is wrong then the other answer is wrong.  Do we have a double standard judgement on this website?

Comment: I believe the other one was first, so yours was redundant.